# Composer package duplicating directories when installing

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, dependency-management

I have a local dependency which is hosted on a private Gitlab repo. I am however, having difficulty pulling this into my project via Composer.

My `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "crmpicco/GolfBundle": "dev-master"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
        "name": "crmpicco/GolfBundle",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "source": {
            "url": "https://git.crmpicco.com/rfc1872/golfbundle.git",
            "type": "git",
            "reference": "master"
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "crmpicco\\GolfBundle\\": ""
            }
        }
        }
    }
],
```

When I look in the vendor directory the directories are doubled-up when I would not expect that, e.g.
`/vendor/crmpicco/GolfBundle/crmpicco/GolfBundle`

When I run a `composer update crmpicco\GolfBundle` I get the following error when Symfony tries to do a cache:clear:

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

[RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted   
  to load class "crmpiccoGolfBundle from namespace "crmpicco\GolfBundle".         
  Did you forget a "use" statement for "crmpicco\GolfBundle\crmpiccoGolfBundle"?   
  in /var/www/crmpicco/symfony/app/AppKernel.php:31
```

What am I missing/doing wrong in my `composer.json` setup?

Bundle dir structure:

```
/crmpicco
   /GolfBundle
      /Component      
      /DependencyInjection
      crmpiccoGolfBundle.php
```

Bundle composer.json:

```
{
  "name": "crmpicco/GolfBundle",
  "type": "library",
  "description": "A Symfony 2 bundle which provides an easy way to handle billing and subscriptions.",
  "license": "MIT", 
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.0",
    "symfony/config": "~2.8.34",
    "symfony/dependency-injection": "~2.8.34",
    "symfony/http-kernel": "~2.8.34",
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "crmpicco\\GolfBundle\\": ""
    }
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste here the directory structure of your GolfBundle and it's `composer.json`?

Comment: @NikitaLeshchev Hi, sure. I've updated the question. I have no `composer.json` in my bundle dir.

Comment: @NikitaLeshchev Apologies for the confusion, I have added the `composer.json` which belongs to my bundle to the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `package` type for repositories which contains valid `composer.json`. This type was designed for packages without `composer.json`, so this file will be completely ignored, same as updates in your package.

In your case it is better to define it as `git`:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://git.crmpicco.com/rfc1872/golfbundle.git"
    }
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. As I see you have wrong `psr-4` autoload config in your bundle's `composer.json`
You have to change it to the following:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "crmpicco\\GolfBundle\\": "crmpicco/GolfBundle"
    }
}
```

Also If you don't want duplicating of dirs, move your bundle's contents to the root dir and then don't change `composer.json` contents. Dirs duplicate because Composer creates dir structure based on `name` property which is also `crmpicco/GolfBundle` in your case.

Comment: This helps and I have managed to get rid of the doubled-up directories, however I cannot seem to load the bundle in my `AppKernel`. Inside `registerBundles` I am doing this: `new crmpicco\GolfBundle\crmpiccoGolfBundle(),` and in my `vendor` directory I have: `/vendor/crmpicco/GolfBundle` which has all the code inside it including `crmpiccoGolfBundle.php` which I am getting the error: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "crmpiccoGolfBundle" from namespace "crmpicco\GolfBundle".` I don't see where I am going wrong here...

Comment: The bundle's `composer.json` `autoload` section looks like this: `"autoload": { "psr-4": { "crmpicco\\GolfBundle\\": "" } },`. I should also point out that I have flushed the composer cache with a `composer clear-cache`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @crmpicco which version of symfony you use?

Comment: I'm on 2.8 LTS.

Comment: @crmpicco Try `composer dump-autoload`. Also check namespace of your class `crmpiccoGolfBundle`. Perhaps there's any error in class naming or namespace